# For which values is the quadratic a perfect square?

Tags: linear-algebra

$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is a quadratic polynomial, $a,b,c$ are natural numbers. For which values of $a,b,c$, $f(x)$ can be a perfect square? If it can be perfect square, for which integer values of $x$ it is so?

Comment: $a,b,c$ are natural numbers.

Comment: The question is too general. The full theory of when there exists $x$ such that $ax^2+bx+c$ is a perfect square is quite extensive.

Comment: @André Nicolas Can you give me the link of that theory?